# How to take 2 values from links Scrapy LinkExtractor

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy

I need take all links from Amazon starting with this one -

```
     https://www.amazon.com/s?k=guess+case&crid=2Q25FH0FOTCA4&sprefix=guess+case%2Caps%2C215&ref=nb_sb_noss
```

But i need only cases Guess. These links must containt 2 values - "Guess" and "Phone". For example:

```
https://www.amazon.com/Guess-Scarlett-Collection-Hard-iPhone/dp/B00QTEP0B0/ref=sr_1_2?crid=2Q25FH0FOTCA4&keywords=guess+case&qid=1650550474&sprefix=guess+case%2Caps%2C215&sr=8-2
    
https://www.amazon.com/Guess-GUHCP13SPCUMABK-Marble-Collection-iPhone/dp/B09J94ZMZ3/ref=sr_1_3?crid=2Q25FH0FOTCA4&keywords=guess+case&qid=1650550474&sprefix=guess+case%2Caps%2C215&sr=8-3
```

How can i take these links with help library re?

```
      start_urls = ['https://www.amazon.com/s?k=guess+case&crid=2Q25FH0FOTCA4&sprefix=guess+case%2Caps%2C215&ref=nb_sb_noss/']

      rules = [Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=r'???' , ))...
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use an if statement...

if 'guess' and 'phone' not in url:

Comment: Thank you for answer. Are you suggesting to do like this? def parse_filter(self, response): item = Product() item['product_url'] = response.url if 'guess' and 'chehol' in response.url: yield item But the spider will bypass all links anf add links with "guess" and "chehol". But i need to spider bypass ONLY links with "guess" and "chehol".

Comment: if 'guess' and 'phone' not in response.url: